# How to build and run Emacs from source with Eclipse?

Tags: build, compile

I have just downloaded the latest version (Oxygen, Release 4.7.0) of the Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, and would like to use it to build and run Emacs from source, which I have downloaded from the Emacs Git repository into ~/emacs/ (it's Emacs version 26.0.50).

I've never used Eclipse before nor built/run Emacs from source before.

I run macOS, the latest version (Sierra, v. 10.12.6).

Comment: Isn't that an Eclipse CDT related question about importing existing projects?

Comment: @jue: Where would be a good place to post this question?

Comment: Anyways, it looks like Emacs source code uses autotools. With this info, you should have a look here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/Autotools/User_Guide . But then: why use Eclipse, if you get Emacs after one build process? :)

Comment: @jue. Thanks. What do you mean by "why use Eclipse, if you get Emacs after one build process? :)" Do mean why not use Emacs as the IDE?

Comment: Yes, I mean use Emacs as IDE. It needs some configuration, but I like it a lot more than Eclipse.

Comment: @jue: I'd rather use a GUI-oriented IDE, since I'm a very amateur programmer and a rather new Emacs user.

Comment: I don't see a reason to do that. It's more work than extracting the tarball, running `./configure`, `make` and `make install`. The worst thing that can happen is that you'll need to get some header files to compile it.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10: Maybe so, but setting breakpoints, watching variables and so on is more intuitive to me in Eclipse.

Comment: Stackoverflow has Eclipse tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse . In general, setting up a C project in Eclipse is an art in and for itself. It'd be hard to answer your question in this format. Also, Eclipse is a more rigid environment than Emacs, and it's very unlikely that there are many people compiling Emacs, who also use Eclipse to do that, so, in the end of the day, you may find that Eclipse is, in principle, incompatible with Emacs source code layout, or that it is very hard to make it do what you want.

Comment: @wvxvw: Thanks. So what would be the top IDEs for building and debugging Emacs from source on a macOS?

Comment: I've heard about people using Code::Blocks, which is more specialized on C++, but would probably work for C too. I didn't use it enough to vouch for or against it. Internet is full of articles comparing various graphical programming environments. My opinion would drown in the sea of arguments about the best one :) I'm also guessing that XCode and TextMate would work better on Mac, since they were designed for that system, but, again, I don't have enough experience to pass judgment. It's fairly rare for someone using Emacs to also be very proficient user of a GUI code editor.